# Coefficient standard error of zero in quantile regression

Tags: standard-error, quantile-regression

I'm currently experimenting with quantile regression of a strongly right skewed outcome variable y on a 3-category exposure x (values 1,2,3). I wanted to model the .2, .5, and .8 quantile, using the interior point algorithm for estimation and bootstrapping (Markov chain marginal bootstrap method, n=1000) for confidence intervals. The software (SAS v9.2) gave no warning about convergence problems or the like.

For the latter two, the results appear reasonable, however, for the .2 quantile, I sometimes get standard errors of 0 for the intercept and both of the two exposure coefficients (dummy coded, 2 vs. 1 and 3 vs. 1).

Group sizes for subgroups defined by x are: 227 (x=1), 423 (x=2), and 90 (x=3). Like I said, y is strongly right skewed, with a range of 0-14 (mostly integer values, but decimal values also exist in the data). Proportion of subjects with y=0 is 31% for x=1, 18% for x=2, and 10% for x=3. I speculated that this might be the reason for the 0 standard errors, but I neither have enough experience with this particular method, nor enough mathematics background to really understand the algorithms.

Therefore my questions: Is it normal to get stanard error of 0 with this method? And what does it imply for the interpretation of these results? Should I drop the analysis of the .2 quantile altogether? Does the validity of the other two quantile regressions (for .5 and .8) remain unaffected by this?

Below is the SAS code I used, and the results of an exemplary analysis. I repeated the analysis 10 times and in 5 cases, standard error were 0 like in the example below, and in the remaining 5, they were between .01 and .10. Results for the .5 and .8 quantile were pretty stable.

PROC QUANTREG DATA=... ALGORITHM=INTERIOR(TOLERANCE=1e-4) CI=RESAMPLING(nrep=1000) ORDER=DATA;
    CLASS x;
    MODEL y = x / QUANTILE = .2 .5 .8;
RUN;

I'd be highly grateful for any comments!

```
Quantile Parameter      x value   Estimate    StdErr       LowerCL      UpperCL

0.2      Intercept                0.0000      0.0000       0.0000       0.0000
0.2      x              3         1.0000      0.0000       1.0000       1.0000
0.2      x              2         1.0000      0.0000       1.0000       1.0000
0.5      Intercept                1.0000      0.0805       0.8419       1.1581
0.5      x              3         3.0000      0.4168       2.1817       3.8183
0.5      x              2         1.0000      0.0828       0.8375       1.1625
0.8      Intercept                3.0000      0.2288       2.5508       3.4492
0.8      x              3         4.2019      0.5462       3.1296       5.2742
0.8      x              2         1.0000      0.2444       0.5203       1.4797
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SE's of zero are obviously highly suspicious.  Usually, and I'm quite confident in
this attribution in the present case, they arise from `summary.rq` when the response
is really discrete and the fitted model decides that zero is a good point estimate
of a covariate effect.  In `summary.rq` the algorithm feels very proud of the fact
that multiple values of the response are all predicted well by the fitted model. Of
course pride goeth before a fall, and so forth, so in these cases I find it useful
to consider perturbations of the data, both response and covariates, which usually
produces something more sensible.  The `quantreg` function `?dither` can be used for 
this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, Roger. It's very nice to have your expertise on these questions.